# Why does my Unity IoC not create a class for me?

Tags: c#

I have the following class declared:

```
public class SeedData
{
    private IUow _uow;

    public SeedData(IUow uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

}
```

and in bootstrapper:

```
container.RegisterType<IUow, Uow>();
```

My code tries to declare an instance like this:

```
var a = new SampleData.EF.SeedData();
```

However I get the message:

```
Error 
'SampleData.EF.SeedData' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

Can someone explain what I can do to make my IoC create an instance of Uow for me. Am I going about 
this the wrong way?

Comment: You need to use the IoC container...

Comment: But how can I get access to that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also put `SeedData` into container:

```
container.RegisterType<SeedData>();
```

And then call:

```
var a = container.Resolve<SeedData>();
```

Instead of creating directly by `new`. With this way, container will inject `IUow` for you automatically.

Comment: [Required reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664762(v=pandp.50).aspx#ResolveObjects_CustomTypes)?

Comment: In my class there is no reference to the container. I think the container is known only in the bootstrapping class.

Comment: `var a = new SampleData.EF.SeedData();` where you call this line, SeedData is entity from EF?

Comment: SeedData is my class. I was hoping to call this line and then the next line would be a.CreateData() as I have a CreateData method in my class. I think the problem is that I did not store any place a reference to container.

Comment: If SeedData is domain object, injecting UoW into domain object is not much corrective, you need to consider your app design

Comment: Sorry. SeedData is not a domain object. It's just a class that holds a method that then uses the unit of work.

Comment: So, inject SeedData into class which contain code `var a = new SampleData.EF.SeedData();` instead of creating by `new`

Answer (score 0):

When you add a public constructor, you override the default one without params.
Try to add public constructor without params, where you will obtain your object from container

Comment: This misses the point, how to use an IoC container to construct an object with dependencies.